# Two standard six sided dice are to be rolled. If the sum is an even number greater than 7, then what is the probability that both dice are even?

Tags: probability, dice

This question is from Mathcounts 2013- 2014, Warm Up 18, Question 253.

1. What formula can you use to find the number of unique dice pairings? *If we have a 3 and a 4, then a 4 and a 3, the two would could as one dice pairing.

I'm thinking that the answer to #1 is 6*2/2. Is this correct?

2. How would you solve the problem as it is written in the title?

Comment: If you consider (3,4) to be the same outcome as (4,3) then there are $\binom{6}{2}+6 = 21$ different possibilities.  Be warned that these are not equally likely to occur.  It is twice as likely to get a three and a four in some order than it is to get two threes.  As for the probability, this can be brute forced pretty easily.  There are relatively few ways to have an even sum greater than seven.  There are $5$ ways to get a sum of eight, $3$ ways to get a sum of $10$ and only one way to get a sum of $12$ (*where order of dice does matter*).  Now, how many of those are accomplished via evens?

Comment: In calculating probability you should treat $(4,3)$ and $(3,4)$ as equally probable distinct outcomes.

Comment: @JMoravitz You mentioned that (62)+6=21 (can't format it properly). What does (62) mean? I've never seen a [term?] formatted like that before.

Comment: It is a [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), an extremely important counting tool that you should become *intimately* familiar with if you are going to spend any time with counting problems or probability problems as it comes up in many common problem types.  $\binom{n}{r}$, read aloud as "n choose r", counts the number of subsets of size $r$ from an $n$-element set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible outcomes are
$$(6,2),\quad (5,3),\quad (4,4),\quad (3,5),\quad (2,6),\quad (6,4),\quad (5,5),\quad (4,6),\quad (6,6)$$
and the successes are
$$(6,2),\quad (4,4),\quad (2,6),\quad (6,4),\quad (4,6),\quad (6,6)\ .$$

So the probability is $\frac69=\frac23$.

**Note**.  The somewhat confusing comment in the first question about $4,3$ being the same as $3,4$ is not relevant.  You can say that for example $(6,2)$ counts the same as $(2,6)$, but then $6,2$ and $4,4$ will not be equally probable, so you can't just rely on counting outcomes and dividing.

Comment: Why won't 6, 2 and 4, 4 be equally probable? If we have (6,2), then we can have (2,6). If we have (4₁,4₂), then we can also have (4₂,4₁). Here, they seem probable.

Comment: The dice are not marked with $4_1,4_2$, they are just marked with $4$.

Comment: I used it to mark the difference between the two 4s. 4₁ would always come from dice A, 4₂ always from dice B.

Comment: Well in that case $(4_2,4_1)$ is impossible because there isn't a $4_2$ on die $A$ and there isn't a $4_1$ on die $B$.